# No view found for id 0x7f0a005b

Tags: android-studio

I've met the problem that trouble me for days.

I have 2 fragments: theFirstFragment & theSecondFragment.
In MainActivity, i call theFirstFragment and it load ok. After that, i make event click on theFirstFragment to change theSecondFragment. It shows error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a005b

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Fragment fragment = new TheFirstFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.activeMain, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activeMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

TheFirstFragment.java

```
public class TheFirstFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

fragment_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background"
    tools:context=".TheFirstFragment">
```

TheSecondFragment.java

```
public class TheSecondFragment extends Fragment
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
            return view;
        }
```

fragment_second

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background"
    tools:context=".TheSecondFragment">
```

Comment: what is **activeMain**.? please provide XML code too.

Comment: @JayPanchal Thanks for your reply! I have recent updated question.

Comment: I solved it. System change page with layout content. Sorry for bother! Please help me close this question!

Comment: But where is you click event in first fragment please put that code too..